# custom form author - auto save author to DB

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

I have a custom form... I'd like to auto save the author (authenticated user) for the form data. I'm using ModelForm for creating the form.

models.py

```
    class Tracker(models.Model):
        client = models.ForeignKey(Clients)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        description = models.TextField()
...
```

I have also linked the custom profile to the django users table... also the auth works fine... I can read the user and id...

forms.py

```
class TrackerForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrackerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.keyOrder = ['date_job_start','date_job_end','description','onsite','billable','client']
    class Meta:
        model = Tracker
        widgets = {
            'client': HiddenInput(),
        }
```

When the form is created from the upper class and I try to save it... it wants the user data (missing warning). How can I change it so that it would automatically save the authenticated user instead of asking for it?? I know that I dont' have the user field defined here... that's because I don't want a dropdown for it... I want the user to be saved from the auth...without any selection or display...

P.S.: I know about the `initial` option... there must be a better way?

Thanks!
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TrackerForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(TrackerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.keyOrder = ['date_job_start','date_job_end','description','onsite','billable','client']

    class Meta:
        model = Tracker
        widgets = {
        '    client': HiddenInput(),
        }
        exclude = ('user',)

    def save(self):
        obj = super(TrackerForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.user
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

And in view:

```
form = TrackerForm(user=request.user) #and other parameters
```

Comment: It works... isn't there any dry-er method? I have a lot of forms... and all of them have to have a user specified...

Comment: I'm kinda new to django... I know how to use inheritance in models... but I don't know how to use it in this example.

Comment: @Mission It isn't django-specific, just usual python inheritance. Create a class (inherited from `ModelForm`), wich will set `self.user` in it's constructor and set this user for obj in `save()` method. And add `exclude = ('user',)` to its `Meta`. Then inherit all the forms which need user from this class. I don't have time to test it, but it will work this way.

Comment: How would I make the user argument optional in the above example? I only need to set if I am creating a new instance of a model object. If I am editing an existing object with a model form, the user is already set for me and I dont need to pass into the constructor.

Comment: @James `self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)` and check if `self.instance` is `True` before saving.